# Php and Mysql multi-lingual pages

Tags: multilingual

I'm new in PHP  I've made a MVC framework after some tutorial and I really learn a lot. I know with a built-in framework like Zend I've could done this easy I think. So what i want to do next is to  build a multilingual site. For start will be only to languages like  Romanian and English.

The problem that I've got is that i will have an option from witch users can  add  new pages to the site after a review of one of the admins, here the base language will be Romanian. So There will be a text at least of 200 words and there could be as many pages as database can keep. SO There should be something like an automatic translation, but this is not good enough thinking this will be a presentation site.

I have looked into tutorials and examples on this but id cannot fine some solution to fix my problem. My pages content will be generated from database. After some wrong solution I have thought to a solution to keep in the db only some id instead of a word/phrase and to that id to correspond some id's from translation table. This is not a good option thinking that there will be no good for adaptation from one language to another.

Can you give me some solution for this? Or can you give me some good tutorials/ examples to map to my problem?

Thank you

Comment: What is your programming question? I mean you write a lot about *your* problem, but it's not clear what the concrete programming issue is.

Comment: If automatic translation is not good enough for your purpose (which it usually isn't), you have to use manual translation. So you need an additional translation process within/after the review process by the admin.

Comment: @hakre is not a problem of code  but more and architectural and what you can do with php in this

Comment: @arkascha is there  a problem what i have in mine is like something semi-automatic translation

Comment: What does 'semi automatic' mean? I take from your question that you try to do a word by word translation. Forget that. I strongly suggest to use manual translation, everything else is just a joke. And you don't want jokes on your page, do you? If there is no translation available then say so on the page, but don't try to offer something you cannot offer seriously.

Comment: @arkascha hm semi automatic i;m thinking like to make a word by word/phrase and if admin don;t like it be able to make some adjustments if he/she wants i'm wondering if that is possible an is worthy

Comment: Again and again: forget word by word translations. Have a few tries yourself, you will see that the results are horrible, even worse than using automatic translation services. I would be ashamed of a page showing such 'translations'.

Comment: Well auto-translate when the original text is put in and leave that result as a suggestion. Mark the result entry as auto-translated, display a warning box on the foreign page(s) and then provide some workflow for the admin to correct things - done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just show English content to people who use the site in English and Romanian content for those using it in Romanian. If I use the site in English and go to your profile I'll see all of your articles even those in Romanian. But when I browse though `latest`, `popular` ... I only see those in English.

Database structure :

**Language table**

```
language_id | language_name | langauge_code
-------------------------------------------
     1      |    English    |      en
     2      |     Român     |      ro
     3      |    Spanish    |      es
```

**Post table**

```
post_id | user_id | language_id | post_title | post_content
------------------------------------------------------------
   23   |    7    |      2      |     ...    |     ...
   24   |    5    |      1      |     ...    |     ...
```

If you really want a translation for everything add a third table, then you would have original language, with options : *also availible in Romanian*, *author : John Doe*,  *translator : Jane Doe* ...

**Translation table**

```
trans_id | post_id | user_id | language_id | post_title | post_content
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    4    |    23   |    4    |      1      |     ...    |     ...
    5    |    23   |    5    |      3      |     ...    |     ...
```

You can't worry too much about translations, I would just translate static content (header, footer, navigation, buttons...), let users post in what ever language they want, if you have comments on your site they will be in lots of languages. Other sites don't worry about it (facebook, twitter, ...).

You may also want to look into `.po` and `.mo` files with [gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_gettext), you can generate translation files which you can use with [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: hm thanks interesting:) solution:) the problem is my site should present some places of Romania and ppl will be able to add a new description of a new place and some admin will be able to let that post to go to the site or not. So putting the admin to make the translation for an article of 1000 words will be messy. This site should be able to present the Romania to the world so bed English is not an option.